# Need Help in Rigidbody based FPS Controller in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I am Learning unity and trying to create a fps game, but while making its controller i am facing a bit problem, like  i want to move player ,, but using rigidbody not the character controller as i want it to completely interact the environment, but when i try to make player move using addforce it works fine but when i stop pressing the moving keys even the player moves for some amount of time, i want a little more snappy movement, should i use addForce or should i move player by using velocity, and can you help me find the counter movement when i stop pressing the movement buttons, using the script not by increasing the friction

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) ? Maybe also in combination with [`Vector3.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add force to a `Rigidbody` to move it you have a couple options on how to slow down that rigidbody.

1. Consider setting the velocity to zero to stop movement instantly
2. Consider Clamping the velocity of the `GameObject`
3. Consider adding additional velocity in the opposite direction the rigid body is traveling.

Set The Velocity

```cs
if(stopPlayer)
{
    rigidbody.Velocity = new Vector3();
}
```

Clamp the Velocity

```cs
Vector3 velocity =  rigidbody.Velocity;
velocity.x = Mathf.Clamp(velocity.x, -MaxVelocity,MaxVelocity);
velocity.y = Mathf.Clamp(velocity.y, -MaxVelocity,MaxVelocity);
velocity.z = Mathf.Clamp(velocity.z, -MaxVelocity,MaxVelocity);
rigidbody.Velocity = velocity;
```

Add Velocity in opposite direction

```cs
Vector3 velocity =  rigidbody.Velocity;
rigidbody.AddForce(-velocity * SlowDownModifier * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```